# How do I structure this data better?

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
class Book {
    let title = ""
    let description = ""
    let ebookPath = ""
    let featuredCategories = [FeaturedCategory]()
    let authors = [Author]()
    let publishers = [Publisher]()
    //...
}

class FeaturedCategory {
    let name = ""
    let books = [Book]()
}

class Author {
    let name = ""
    let books = [Book]()
}

class Publisher {
    let name = ""
    let books = [Book]()
}


class Tag {
    let name = ""
    let books = [Book]()
}
```

As you can see from the code above, there is a lot of repetition. This becomes even more ugly if I add more classes with the same variables `name` and `books`. What is a better alternative?

Edit: I'm downloading JSON from Firebase. Here's the JSON structure:

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: Would be good to include more detail in the question. "This data" is very vague.

Comment: Do you have a JSON for the above?

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: In class Book, you have added 'authors' variable two times. This cause compile time error "Invalid redeclaration of authors". Please check it.

Comment: I posted the code as an example. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm this question could be answered in many ways but i will try to share my opinion on it.

Firstly try to use `struct` instead of the `class` because in this way you are more flexible in architecture.

Secondly use `protocol` for creating of the relationships.

Small example :

```
//Struct insted of class
struct Book {
    //Usage of the let in struct is good practice.
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let ebookPath: String
    let featuredCategories: [FeaturedCategory]
}

//Base protocol
protocol HasBooks {
    var name: String { get }
    var books: [Book] { get }
}

//Strcut that reuqires to implement name and books.
struct FeaturedCategory : HasBooks {
    var name = ""
    var books = [Book]()
}
```

Comment: I'd choose a name something like HasBooks for the protocol. Something more descriptive than BaseData anyway.

Comment: This is a better improvement however what if I have, let's say, 20 structs with the same exact data? Wouldn't that be a bit too strange?